# How can I chart 3d scatter graphs in C++?

Tags: c++, 3d, plot, scatter-plot

What is the best way to chart a 3D scatter graph in C++?

Or maybe it's easier to use an external programs. Can you recommend my anything?

Comment: What platform are you on? How do you want the output to be displayed or stored? How should it integrate with the rest of the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll want is some form of GUI library - you could use, say, ncurses, but graphs in a terminal are rather difficult. Any GUI library will do it.

[FLTK](http://fltk.org) is the easiest to pick up and can definitely accommodate your problem, but [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) should also do it, along with [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) et al.

Failing that, OpenGL is probably a hacky way to get it done!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Did you heard about ChartDirector. I used to use it but don't know if they have a 3D scatter chart. Try http://www.advsofteng.com/[1](http://www.advsofteng.com/)